# Why is Graphics::DrawString drawing misc characters?

Tags: c++, gdi+, gdi

I am trying to use GDI+ to draw text onto an image, however, I notice that with DrawString(...) there is my text, followed by several misc characters (it looks like maybe Japanese). These characters only show up when using DrawString, and I notice by saving the Bitmap to a file. Does anyone know what may be causing this? My GDI Code is

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;

int main(void)
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR           gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    Font* myFont = new Font(L"Times New Roman", 10);
    Bitmap* characterBitmap = new Bitmap(256, 256, PixelFormat32bppARGB);
    Graphics* g = new Graphics(characterBitmap);

    g->Clear(Color::Transparent);

    SolidBrush* myBrush = new SolidBrush(Color::Black);
    g->DrawString(L"TEST", 48, myFont, PointF(0, 0), myBrush);

    CLSID pngClsid;
    GetEncoderClsid(L"image/png", &pngClsid);
    characterBitmap->Save(L"test.png",  &pngClsid, NULL);

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the documentation of the [`Graphics::DrawString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535993%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

The second parameter should be:

> Integer that specifies the number of characters in the string array. The length parameter can be set to –1 if the string is null terminated.